# Abstract constants to use with generics

Tags: c#, generics, constants

I have multiple classes. Each one have two constants defined (the constants values differ, but I know every class has this 2 constants). Those constants are used as values for a DbColumn Attribute (It's not possible to use Properties instead). I want to use this classes as generics in another class and get the value of the constants. 
Here's a little example:

```
public abstract class BaseAssignment
{
    //Won't work
    public (abstract) const string Item;
    public (abstract) const string AssignedItem;
}

public class AssignemtA : BaseAssignment
{
    public const string Item = "A";
    public const string AssignedItem = "1";

    [DbColumn(Item)]
    ...
    [DbColumn(AssignedItem)]
    ...
}

public class AssignmentB : BaseAssignment
{
    public const string Item = "B";
    public const string AssignedItem = "2";

    [DbColumn(Item)]
    ...
    [DbColumn(AssignedItem)]
    ...
}

public class AssignmentHandler<Tobj> where Tobj : BaseAssignment
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Tobj.AssignedItem);
    }
}
```

The BaseAssignment class would not work, because it's not possible to define a abstract constant. Is there any possibility to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract and constants are orthogonal. Constants are kind of static member, whereas abstract means it participates in inheritance and which should be a instance member.

My suggestion is to use abstract property. If you can't use properties, then you'll have to use reflection to read the constant value.

Here's how you do with reflection:

```
public class AssignmentHandler<TObj> where TObj : BaseAssignment
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var assignedItemField = typeof(TObj).GetField("AssignedItem", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        Console.WriteLine(assignedItemField .GetRawConstantValue());
    }
}
```

<sub>Note:Even if you use abstract property, you can't use `Tobj.AssignedItem`. You need a instance of `Tobj` to read the property.</sub>

Comment: This is indeed the only solution that meets OP's requirement of being able to use the `const` in attributes. Reflection is the way to go.

Comment: Btw, properties are a no go since you can't use them in the attributes.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You can still have a constant member which is applied to a attribute and you can use the same constant member to return from the property :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman I mean keep the constant and attribute as it is, add a property `public string MyProperty { get { return AssignedItem; } }`. But I think it doesn't make much sense as OP's requirement is not a good fit for properties (as you need instance of a class to begin with).

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, but maybe OP didn't, so maybe it is good to clarify your answer on the properties part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As you already stated, using properties doesn't meet my requirements, i don't want to create a instance of the class. Reflection would be a bit to expensive, to just receive a single string. I think I will add a property for each constant to the AssignmentHandler and fill them creation.